# Use Terraform to create folder and subfolder in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

How can I create folder and subfolder in S3 bucket using Terraform?

This is how my current code look like.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "Fruits" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_name.id}"
  key    = "${var.folder_fruits}/"
  content_type = "application/x-directory"
}

variable "folder_fruits" {
  type = string
}
```

I would need a folder structure like fruits/apples

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Folders in S3 are simply objects that end with a `/` character. You should be able to create the `fruits/apples/` folder with the following Terraform code:

```
variable "folder_fruits" {
  type = string
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "fruits" {
  bucket       = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_name.id}"
  key          = "${var.folder_fruits}/"
  content_type = "application/x-directory"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "apples" {
  bucket       = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_name.id}"
  key          = "${var.folder_fruits}/apples/"
  content_type = "application/x-directory"
}
```

It is likely that this would also work without the `fruits` folder.

For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

Comment: By the way, you are not required to create folders in a bucket before uploading objects. S3 does not behave like a filesystem in this regard. Behind the scenes, the objects are stored in a "flat structure".

Comment: It's a requirement since we have to distinguish other files also. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The above Terraform code that you posted helped me in solving my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a null object with a prefix that ends with '/'. All objects in a bucket are at the same hierarchy level but AWS displays it like folders using '/' as the separator.

```
    resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "fruits" {
    bucket = "your-bucket"
    key    = "fruits/"
    source = "/dev/null"

    resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "apples" {
    bucket = "your-bucket"
    key    = "fruits/apples/"
    source = "/dev/null"
}
```

It creates the following folder like structure:

```
s3://your-bucket/fruits/
s3://your-bucket/fruits/apples/
```